# Как проверять, перешел ли пользователь discord по ссылке python?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

По заказу мне нужно сделать следующее.
Чтобы бот discord отправлял пользователю при входе на сервер ссылку, по которой он должен перейти, дабы авторизоваться. Вопрос следующий: как и где взять подобную ссылку и связать ее с Python?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.